# Output list of variables with significant p-values from several regressions in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have a dataframe that looks like the following.

```
consistent  admire  trust  judge 
3           3       2      4
5           1       3      6
2           4       5      1
```

I can run the regressions I need simultaneously using the following code. In the actual dataset, there are many more than 3 variables.

```
variables <- c("admire", "trust", "judge")
form <- paste("consistent ~ ",variables,"")
model <- form %>% 
  set_names(variables) %>%
  map(~lm(as.formula(.x), data = df))
map(model, summary)
```

This yields the output for the 3 following regressions.

```
summary(lm(consistent ~ admire, df))
summary(lm(consistent ~ trust, df))
summary(lm(consistent ~ judge, df))
```

I would like a list of the variables with significant p-values at p < 0.05. For example, if "admire" was significant and "judge" was significant, the output I am looking for would be something like:

```
admire, judge
```

Is there a way to do this that allows me to also run several regressions simultaneously? This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860198/subset-variables-by-significant-p-value) offers a similar answer, but I don't know how to apply it when I have several regressions.

Data:

```
structure(list(consistent = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), admire = c(7, 
3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 7, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 5, 
3, 1, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1, 
7, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 5, 5, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 1, 3, 5, 
5, 1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 5, 1, 4, 4, 3, 5, 6, 1, 5, 2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 3, 
3, 5, 6, 1, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5, 4, 1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 6, 1, 
3, 7, 4, 4, 3, 2, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 2, 
4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 6, 1, 2, 4, 7, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 4, 
7, 5, 6, 3, 1, 1, 7, 1, 6, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 4, 7, 
2, 1, 5, 3, 3, 7, 4, 5, 1, 3, 7, 5, 4, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 4, 
1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 4, 4, 4, 7, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 6, 
5, 6, 7, 4, 4, 5, 1, 5, 7, 1, 7, 2, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 7, 3, 5, 4, 
1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 6, 6, 7, 3, 4, 1, 6, 4, 1, 6, 7, 5, 4, 2, 6, 
5, 5, 4, 1, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 3, 5, 1, 5, 1, 7, 2, 
5, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 5, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 
2, 7, 6, 6, 4, 3, 6, 1, 6, 1, 1, 4, 7, 7, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 4, 2, 5, 5, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 7, 2, 2, 4, 5, 1, 6, 2, 5, 1, 5, 6, 2, 5, 1, 1, 7, 4, 5, 6, 
1, 4, 5, 2, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 2, 6, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 5, 3, 7, 
5, 6, 4, 3, 4, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 7, 2, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 
1, 6, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 
6, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6, 7, 3, 2, 4, 2, 5, 
1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1), trust = c(7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 
1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 6, 6, 4, 1, 3, 6, 5, 4, 6, 1, 
5, 1, 6, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 7, 1, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 
3, 5, 2, 6, 5, 3, 2, 6, 6, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 1, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 1, 
4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 3, 5, 6, 1, 6, 5, 2, 2, 2, 5, 7, 1, 5, 3, 7, 3, 
5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 2, 1, 6, 5, 2, 6, 5, 1, 2, 7, 6, 5, 3, 3, 4, 7, 
4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 7, 6, 2, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 1, 2, 7, 1, 
1, 5, 4, 1, 4, 6, 6, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 5, 7, 6, 7, 3, 2, 1, 7, 1, 
4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 6, 3, 1, 4, 3, 7, 2, 2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 5, 7, 
2, 4, 7, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 4, 
6, 1, 1, 2, 6, 2, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
7, 1, 7, 3, 7, 5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 1, 5, 4, 
7, 3, 5, 1, 6, 6, 1, 4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 7, 6, 5, 4, 1, 1, 6, 1, 5, 
3, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 3, 4, 1, 4, 1, 7, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 
4, 6, 5, 2, 4, 5, 4, 1, 6, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 7, 5, 6, 4, 4, 6, 2, 
6, 1, 2, 4, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 6, 
4, 1, 6, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6, 
2, 5, 1, 3, 7, 1, 4, 1, 1, 7, 5, 6, 5, 1, 5, 5, 1, 4, 3, 7, 4, 
4, 1, 7, 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 4, 5, 5, 4, 7, 6, 7, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
1, 1, 5, 6, 2, 7, 4, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 
3, 4, 3, 1, 2, 6, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 7, 4, 4, 5, 6, 2, 5, 3, 
4, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 6, 7, 4, 4, 3, 2, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 3, 1
), judge = c(1, 5, 6, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 
4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 7, 5, 4, 4, 1, 3, 6, 2, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 
4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 
1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 7, 3, 3, 1, 1, 5, 
3, 3, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 
2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 6, 1, 7, 4, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 7, 2, 3, 5, 5, 1, 2, 2, 5, 
6, 5, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 4, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 
3, 4, 7, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2, 6, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 1, 6, 7, 5, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 
5, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 
2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 6, 1, 
5, 7, 5, 4, 2, 3, 6, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 2, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
3, 7, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4, 6, 4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 2, 6, 
4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 7, 1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 5, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 
5, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5, 4, 6, 3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 5, 
1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 6, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 6, 1, 5, 1, 3, 3, 
1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 6, 5, 4, 1, 7, 5, 6, 5, 2, 
3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 7, 1, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 7, 5, 5, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 5, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 5, 
6, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-450L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit many many simple linear regression models, I recommend [Fast pairwise simple linear regression between variables in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51953709/4891738). Hmm... looks like I need to collect those functions in an **R** package...

```
## suppose your data frame is `df`
## response variable (LHS) in column 1
## independent variable (RHS) in other columns
out <- general_paired_simpleLM(df[1], df[-1])
#         LHS    RHS      alpha       beta     beta.se   beta.tv      beta.pv
#1 consistent admire -0.1458455 0.18754326 0.008324192 22.529906 1.040756e-75
#2 consistent  trust -0.2211250 0.19565589 0.007721387 25.339475 1.531499e-88
#3 consistent  judge  0.3484851 0.04824981 0.014182420  3.402086 7.287372e-04
#        sig         R2      F.fv         F.pv
#1 0.3430602 0.53118295 507.59665 1.040756e-75
#2 0.3212008 0.58902439 642.08902 1.531499e-88
#3 0.4946862 0.02518459  11.57419 7.287372e-04
```

To get what you want:

```
with(out, RHS[beta.pv < 0.05])
#[1] "admire" "trust"  "judge"
```